# Bitcoin.conf "blocksdir" parameter not taking effect?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf, datadir

I am running Bitcoin core on a raspberry pi with an external ssd. I am using this line in the bitcoin.conf to move block storage onto the ssd: `blocksdir=/media/bitcoinstorage/.bitcoin/blocks`

However, when I run bitcoind, blocks still get written to the default location at ~/.bitcoin/blocks

This is what I've tried so far:

Running with these flags:

```
bitcoind -conf=path/to/conf -blockdir=/media/bitcoinstorage/.bitcoin/blocks
```

Precreating the .bitcoin/blocks directories in the desired location.

Setting permissions on both directories involved (media and bitcoinstorage) to 777 to no avail. The default permissions for using /media required sudo - I don't know much about how permissions work and if they're inherited so I'm guessing this might have something to do with it.

Each time in between I have deleted the .bitcoin directory entirely and done `bitcoin-cli stop` before trying again. It seems like no matter what I do I cannot change the default blocks storage location.

Any help would be appreciated here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your flag. It reads `blockdir` but it should be `blocksdir`.